# javascript reduce in function

Tags: javascript, function, reduce

I am brand new to javascript and have only an entry level java college course under my belt. I am taking a course online to learn JS and have run into a hiccup. I am supposed to create a function that parses a string and finds the longest word.
I figured the problem out, but could not understand why the following function was giving me an undefined. Any help would be great as I try to deeper my understanding of the language.

```js
var statement = 'This is an example string'
//undefined

var result = statement.split(' ').reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (acc.length > cur.length) {
    return acc;
  } else {
    return cur;
  }
});

console.log(result);  //"example"

function longest(string) {
  string.split(' ').reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    if (acc.length > cur.length) {
      return acc;
    } else {
      return cur;
    }
  });
}

result = longest(statement);
console.log(result);  //undefined
```

Comment: `longest()` doesn't return anything -> `undefined`

Comment: You are missing a `return` keyword: `return string.split(' ')...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should return something. If you don't 'return' any values in JavaScript, it will return 'undefined'

In your problem, your function has a reduce method which returns a value inside your 'longest' function. But, the 'longest' function should return the value. So that the value will be available when u invoke this function

```
function longest(string){ 
   return string.split('').reduce(function(acc,cur){
       if (acc.length > cur.length){
          return acc;
       } else { 
          return cur; 
       } 
   }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a return from the function.

```js
var statement = 'This is an example string'
//undefined

function longest(string) {
  var result = string.split(' ').reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    if (acc.length > cur.length) {
      return acc;
    } else {
      return cur;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

result = longest(statement);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to achieve the same result would be to to split the array into words and then simply [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it in descending order by word length ... then just pick the first element.

```js
var statement = 'This is an example string'
var result = statement.split(' ').sort((x,y) => y.length - x.length)[0]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a value from your function. There are special types of functions called Arrow Functions in JavaScript which let you avoid using the return statement. It works only for one-line statements, though.
 More on arrow functions can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Here's how my solution would look like:

```js
const statement = 'This is an example string';
const longest = string => 
  string.split(' ').reduce((acc, cur) => acc.length > cur.length? acc: cur);
console.log(longest(statement));
```